# Second HttpURLConnection is failing

Tags: android, exception, httpurlconnection

I have a `ListView` that `onLongClick` it calls a method that is supposed to go out to a website, pull a `jsonArray` from it and then return information that is pulled from the array.  However, when it calls the `HttpURLConnection.connect()` method it fails and goes to the catch block.  When I use the `getMessage()` message on the exception it only returns `Null`.  This is the second time in this program that I've connected to a URL in this same way and it works the first time perfectly.  What could be causing this issue?

Here is the code for when the method is called:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {

        String trainNum = list.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        String info = "hello";
        try {
             info = getCurrentTrainInfo(trainNum);
        }catch(Exception e){
           info = e.getMessage();
            if(info == null)
                info = "info is null";
            tv.setText(info);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }
}
);
```

And here is the method `getCurrentTrainInfo` that is called in the try block above:

```
public String getCurrentTrainInfo(String num) throws IOException{

    String sURL = "http://www3.septa.org/hackathon/RRSchedules/" + num;

    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    HttpURLConnection request2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request2.connect();

    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
    JsonArray rootArr = root.getAsJsonArray();
    int i = 0;
    String acTime = "";

    String station = rootArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("station").getAsString();
    String schTime = rootArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("sched_tm").getAsString();
    String esTime = rootArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("est_tm").getAsString();

    tv.setText(station);

    String info = "Current Station: " + station + "\nScheduled leave time: " + schTime + "\nEstimated leave time: " + esTime;*/

    return info;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: use the stacktrace from the exeception and post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your request is being made ​​in the `UI thread`, you mentioned that in another moment used this same way and it worked, I believe this may have happened when you ran your application on a device/emulator with a version of `Android` prior to 3.0.

> Within an `Android` application you should avoid performing long
>   running operations on the user `interface thread`. This includes file
>   and network access. `StrictMode` allows to setup policies in your
>   application to avoid doing incorrect things. As of `Android 3.0
>   (Honeycomb) StrictMode` is configured to crash with a
>   `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception, if network is accessed in
>   the user `interface thread`.

You can create a [AsyncTasks](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) class and move the call request to it.